# The Availability Doesn't Function When The App Is Started From the Command LIne

Tags: spring-shell

I encounter a few unreasonable issues with a Spring Shell app which has the dependency as

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.shell</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-shell-starter</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
```

The availability of a command method works fine when the app is running inside of Intellij Idea, but not on a command line with

```
java -jar target/my-app.jar
```

Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the latest GA version of Spring Shell instead of a SNAPSHOT:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.shell</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-shell-starter</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.4</version>
</dependency>
```